# Elasticsearch stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I successfully installed elasticsearch along with the fulltextsearch in nextcloud following the information provided [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/fulltextsearch/wiki/Basic-Installation).

The search worked fine. Recently I noticed that the elasticsearch service failed to start properly. When I manually restarted initially the serviced seemed to run fine.

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Di 2018-04-10 12:10:15 CEST; 1s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 5958 (java)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 432.7M
      CPU: 1.391s
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           └─5958 /usr/bin/java -Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=t...
```

But after about 10 seconds it stoped with:

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Di 2018-04-10 12:10:23 CEST; 24s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 5958 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5958 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 10 12:10:15 Ubuntu-Server systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Apr 10 12:10:23 Ubuntu-Server systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 10 12:10:23 Ubuntu-Server systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 10 12:10:23 Ubuntu-Server systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am running elasticsearch version 6.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 with java version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

I would like to provide more detailed error logs, but I do not know where to search for them. Please tell me which information is needed and where to find it.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried upgrading Virtual Memory max map count?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Without that change ES is shutting down right after it starts.

If so, try to post more info from logs.
Logs should be located here:

`/var/log/elasticsearch`
`/var/log/syslog`

or by typing:

`journalctl -xe` and find something about: `"Elasticsearch (....) exited"`